# Why is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k!}{\prod_{j=0}^{k} \left(2j+3\right)} = 2-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and how is this solution derived?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, products

I recently came across the problem:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k!}{\prod_{j=0}^{k} \left(2j+3\right)}$$ and decided to try finding its solution. I started off by writing a program that gave me the answer $0.4292036732051...$ which I found probably meant the solution was $2-\frac{\pi}{2}$, but I wanted to see if I could prove it. I started by manipulating the denominator into a double factorial resulting in:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k!}{\left(2k+3\right)!!}$$
Then, I thought things would be easier to work with if I only had regular factorials. This gave me:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{4\cdot2^k k! \left(k+2\right)!}{\left(2k+4\right)!}$$
I unfortunately had little clue to go from here considering I haven't dealt with factorials often, much less in infinite series such as this one. I am curious how it is possible to go forth from here and also how to solve infinite series that are similarly structured. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If we could find $\sum\limits_{k \ge 0} x^k/\binom{2k+4}{k+2},$ a bit of integration would seal the deal.

Comment: By reindexing, we only need to know $\sum\limits_{k \ge 0} x^k/\binom{2k}{k}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We  obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k!}{(2k+3)!!}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k!(2k+2)!!}{(2k+3)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k!2^{k+1}(k+1)!}{(2k+3)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\frac{2^k}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\frac{2^{k-1}}{2k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\frac{2^{k-1}}{2k+3}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We use a representation of reciprocal binomial coefficients via the *[Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)*:

\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_0^1z^k(1-z)^{n-k}\,dz\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> and the left-hand series of (1) can be calculated as
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\frac{2^{k-1}}{2k+1}}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty  2^{k-1}\int_0^1z^k(1-z)^k\,dz\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(2z(1-z)\right)^k\,dz\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^1\frac{dz}{1-2z(1-z)}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dz}{z^2+(1-z)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{du}{1+u^2}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\pi}{4}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3)  we use  the identity (2).
- In (4) we apply the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (5) we use the substitution $u=\frac{1-z}{z}, du=-\frac{1}{z^2}dz$.

We also want to apply (2) to the right-hand series  of (1). To do this conveniently we need some preparatory work:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty&\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\frac{2^{k-1}}{2k+3}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k!k!}{(2k)!}\cdot\frac{2^{k-1}}{2k+3}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k!(k+1)!(2k+1)}{(2k+1)!(k+1)}\cdot\frac{2^{k-1}}{2k+3}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(k+1)!(k+1)!}{(2k+2)!}\cdot\frac{2^{k+1}}{2k+3}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k!(k+1)!}{(2k+1)!(k+1)}\cdot\frac{2^{k-1}}{2k+3}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k+2}{k+1}^{-1}\frac{2^{k+1}}{2k+3}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\frac{2^{k-1}}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k+2}{k+1}^{-1}\frac{2^{k+1}}{2k+3}
-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\frac{2^{k-2}}{2k+1}
+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\frac{2^{k-2}}{2k+3}\tag{7}\\
\end{align*}
In the last line (7) we use a partial fraction decomposition as we did in (1).

> We are now well prepared to do the calculation. We obtain together with (6):
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\frac{2^{k-2}}{2k+3}}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k+2}{k+1}^{-1}\frac{2^{k+1}}{2k+3}-\frac{\pi}{8}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{k+1}\int_{0}^1z^{k+1}(1-z)^{k+1}\,dz-\frac{\pi}{8}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty2^k\int_{0}^1z^k(1-z)^k\,dz-\frac{\pi}{8}\\
> &=\frac{\pi}{2}-2^0\int_{0}^1\,dz-\frac{\pi}{8}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{3}{8}\pi-1}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}
>
> We finally conclude from (1) together with (6) and (8)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k!}{(2k+3)!!}}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\frac{2^{k-1}}{2k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\frac{2^{k-1}}{2k+3}\\
> &=\frac{\pi}{4}-2\left(\frac{3}{8}\pi-1\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2-\frac{\pi}{2}}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from
$$4\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^k k! \left(k+2\right)!}{\left(2k+4\right)!} $$Consider
$$4\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!  (k+2)!}{ (2 k+4)!}(2t)^{2k}$$ and, now, the trick is to recognize (not so obvious) that this is
$$\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2} }{t^3}\sin ^{-1}(t)$$ Make $t=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$ and get the result.

Comment: This is helpful, but I don't understand anything about the final equivalence. Does this have something to do with a Taylor series or is it something else?

Comment: @KirkFox. This is exactly the point ! It is the infinite Taylor expansion. As I wrote, it took me time to find it. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{k! \over \prod_{j = 0}^{k}\pars{2j + 3}} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{k! \over 2^{k + 1}\prod_{j = 0}^{k}\pars{j + 3/2}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{k! \over 2^{k + 1}\pars{3/2}^{\overline{k + 1}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{k + 1}}\,{k! \over 
\Gamma\pars{3/2 + k + 1}/\Gamma\pars{3/2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\,{1 \over 2^{k + 1}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{k + 1}\Gamma\pars{3/2} \over \Gamma\pars{k + 5/2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{k + 1}}\,
\int_{0}^{1}t^{k}\pars{1 - t}^{1/2}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}\root{1 - t}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{t \over 2}^{k}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{\root{1 - t} \over 2 - t}\,\dd t
\,\,\,\stackrel{t\ =\ 1 - x^{2}}{=}\,\,\,
2\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - {1 \over 1 + x^{2}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{2 - {\pi \over 2}}\ \approx\ 0.4292
\end{align}